# Who founded Science Fiction and Fantasy?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

This seems to be a community-run site, but who founded it?

Comment: Now _that's_ a Meta question!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Users did in essence. Sites on Stack Exchange are created by going through [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) (or at least were). If enough users like the proposal and participate on the site that it gets enough content and traffic the site is created. You can see the original proposal for [Science Fiction and Fantasy on Area 51 here](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4451/science-fiction-fantasy).

If you're interested you may want to look at the [main meta FAQ for proposing a new site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76974/345161) and the [Area 51's own FAQ](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Worth mentioning who originally proposed it; https://area51.stackexchange.com/users/38/juanformoso

Comment: @Valorum It's on the sidebar of the proposal.

Comment: Interestingly, although Juan proposed the site, his involvement has been marginal, it seems; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20/juan?tab=topactivity

Comment: @Valorum Possibly because some of the suggested questions he had in mind were not a good fit for the Q&A format.